# web api authentication for 3rd parties and javascript

Tags: .net, security, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am currently implementing web api in my mvc4 application and have a question around authenticating the caller of the web api service.

In my web application, web api will be used for 2 different reasons. Firstly, for my javascript communicate to the server, secondly for third party components communicating with my application.

Because of this, I would like to authenticate the caller of the service. Passing a username and password in the header for either caller is straight forward but the header can be sniffed by illegitimates. If I make the services https, this will prevent against this, but it causes performance issues for my js to be calling it in rich application.

I have looked at examples on the web for this, but cant find a solution as of yet that covers off both of mt scenarios and secures my services. I am interested to hear suggestions as how to solve this problem? For example, how do existing companies secure their services ie twitter. I want to secure my services, to allowable third parties and my javascript. Please educate me!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use digital signing.  The client computes a hash of the request data (POST or GET parameters) and signs the hash with a key, putting the signature in a request header.  The server then verifies the signed hash.

To protect against replay attacks, you would want each request to include a nonce value that can never be re-used.  This is usually implemented as an ever increasing integer value (e.g. a timestamp) where the server stores the last used value for a given key and refuses to allow requests with a number lower than that last used value.

There are two common ways to implement this, one would be using HMAC signatures where the client and server share a common 'secret' (key) that is used to sign requests.  This is simple, but requires you to store the secrets on the server (and protect them appropriately).

The second way would be using asymmetric keys (e.g. RSA) where the client signs the request with their private key and you validate the signature with their public key.  This is slightly more complex, but doesn't require you to store and protect the private key on the server - only the client needs to have that.

Comment: Thanks for providing information on this - how could I implement such for javascript calls?

Comment: @amateur - Not sure why you would need to do this for javascript calls.  An AJAX call from Javascript should be done in the context of the user's session.  Since the user is presumably already logged into the site, and you would have an authentication token for them in the session already, why would you need to authenticate them again?

Comment: thanks for your reply. A user may not be logged in to the site, a user can browse the site without be logged in. Hence trying to secure from this?

Comment: So you're trying to prevent a user that isn't logged in from seeing certain information?  If that's the case, in the controller action that handles the AJAX request, simply check if a user is logged in or not.  If not, don't return any data, otherwise return whatever data is appropriate for the user.